# Understanding the relationship between Spin$^c$ orientations and Spin$^c$ structures

Tags: principal-bundles, spin-geometry, k-homology

I'm looking for some guidance in understanding and writing down a proof of the following statement, concerning the relationship between Spin$^c$ structures and Spin$^c$ orientations, from an expository paper by Baum and van Erp:

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1604.03502.pdf.

The statement I'm concerned about, on page 6, is: 
*"Note that a Spin$^c$ structure is a Euclidean structure plus a Spin$^c$ orientation."*

This comes after the following definition: *"An isomorphism of Spin$^c$ data $(P,\eta),(P',\eta')$ for a vector bundle $F$ is an isomorphism of the principal Spin$^c(n)$ bundles $P\cong P'$ that commutes with the maps $\eta,\eta'$. Two Spin$^c$ data $(P,\eta),(P',\eta')$ for $F$ are homotopic if there exists a $C^\infty$ homotopy $(P,\eta_t)$ of Spin$^c$ data such that $\eta_0=\eta$ and $(P,\eta_1)$ is isomorphic to $(P',\eta')$."*

It's clear enough that a Spin$^c$ structure determines a Spin$^c$ orientation, but how do choices of Spin$^c$ structure within a homotopy class correspond to choices of "Euclidean structure" (which I take to mean a choice of metric)? I'd much appreciate it if someone familiar with the details could say a few words about this. Cheers!